how to get the selected equipment object
we have used forge viewer to display the BIM models. But if we click any equipment listed in the tree selection, In the forge viewer equipment not zooming.
How to get the selected equipment zooming in the forge viewer?
We have used below code:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
     // Get the viewer div
     const viewerDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');

     // Initialize the viewer object
     const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
     viewer.start();

     // Ensure event listeners are added only once
     viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT, onToolbarCreated);
     viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, Loadedevent);

     // Initialize the AggregatedView
     const view = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();
     view.init(viewerDiv, options3d);

     // Use the same viewer instance
     const aggregatedViewer = view.viewer; 

     // Set custom profile settings
     const customProfileSettings = {
         settings: {
             reverseMouseZoomDir: true,
             reverseHorizontalLookDirection: true,
             selectionMode: 1 // enum value, 0 is default 'First Object' is 1
         }
     };

     const customProfile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customProfileSettings);
     viewer.setProfile(customProfile);
 
     // Optimize viewer settings
     viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false); // Disable ambient occlusion and antialiasing
     viewer.setGroundShadow(false); // Disable ground shadow
     viewer.setGroundReflection(false); // Disable ground reflection
     viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true); // Enable progressive rendering
 
     // Load all manifests
     const tasks = models.map(md => loadManifest(md.urn, aggregatedViewer)); 
     Promise.all(tasks)
         .then(docs => Promise.resolve(docs.map(doc => {
             const bubbles = doc.getRoot().search({ type: 'geometry', role: '3d' });
             const bubble = bubbles[0];
             if (!bubble) return null;
             return bubble;
         })))
         .then(bubbles => view.setNodes(bubbles));
 });
 
 // loadManifest function

 function loadManifest(documentId, viewer) {
     debugger;
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (doc) => {
             doc.downloadAecModelData(() => resolve(doc));

             // New code for handling selection changes
             viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (event) => {
                if (!event.selections || event.selections.length <= 0 || event.selections.length > 1) return; 
                 const selSet = event.selections[0];
                 const dbIds = selSet.dbIdArray;
                 const model = selSet.model;
                 const dbId = dbIds[0];
 
                 model.getProperties(dbId, function (data) {
                     if (FromPage == '') {
                         if (FromSelection == '') {
                             if (Count === 0) {
                                 let instanceTree = model.getInstanceTree();
                                 let parentId = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(dbId);
                                 var objectid = parentId + 1;
                                 if (objectid === PreviousParentId) {
                                     Count = 1;
                                     selectionchangecount = 0;
                                 } else {
                                     viewer.select(parentId, model, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED);
                                     // or viewer.setAggregateSelection([ { ids: [parentId ], model, selectionType: Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED } ])
                                     Count = 1;
                                     selectionchangecount = 0;
                                 }
                                 PreviousParentId = parentId;

                             } else {
                                 itemobject = dbId;
                                 selectionchangecount = selectionchangecount + 1;
                                 if (selectionchangecount == fileselectioncount) {
                                     Count = 0;
                                     selectionchangecount = 0;
                                 }
                             }
                         } else {
                             selectionchangecount = selectionchangecount + 1;
                             if (selectionchangecount == filecount) {
                                 FromSelection = '';
                                 selectionchangecount = 0;
                             }
                             itemobject = dbId;
                         }
                     } else {
                         FromPage = '';
                         itemobject = dbId;
                     }

                 });
             });
         };
 
         Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, reject);
     });
}

need solution for zooming the equipment.

By default, selecting an element in the model browser panel does focus the camera on the element. Try going to https://aps-simple-viewer-nodejs.autodesk.io/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cGV0cmJyb3otc2FtcGxlcy9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0, and select any element in the model browser. It's possible that it is some other settings in your application that is changing this default behavior.
Alternatively, you could achieve the same behavior by adding a custom event handler to the viewer, like so:
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function () {
    viewer.fitToView(viewer.getSelection());
})

